# Player for On Demand Music Streaming

Tags: audio-streaming

What players could be used for a small scale On Demand Music Streaming Website. I have heard jplayer allows download too. Are there players that allow only streaming and no downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to prevent users from downloading your music, if they can stream it.  This has nothing to do with which player you use.  If you can hear it, you can record it.  If you can stream it, you can save it.  There is absolutely no way around this.

Follow some best practices for preventing unauthorized media access, such as requiring a current session on your site before allowing streaming.  Rate limit media requests by session and IP address.  These methods will prevent mass downloading and sharing of a URL of your media, but it's still entirely possible for someone to download your audio.

Finally, watermark your files if you're really concerned about it.  That way if someone distributes your media, you can trace it back to the source.